# Cloning a bootstrap element with an event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, clone

I'm trying to clone a bootstrap element that has data-toggle behavior provided by bootstrap:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<button aria-expanded="false" data-target="#collapsible_obj_0" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-link collapsed">click here</button>
<div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapsible_obj_0" class="collapse">
  <span>foo</span>
</div>
</div>
```

After cloning, I am changing the `ID` of the **div** to a new unique id, and the `data-target` of the button to point to the **new div**.

**JS**

```
  var header = objectContainer.clone(true);
  var counter = this.collapsibleObjCounter++;
  var collapseId = "collapsible_obj_" + counter;
  header.find(".collapse").attr("id", collapseId);
  header.find("button[data-toggle='collapse']").attr("data-target", "#"+collapseId);
```

The button and div are children of the object container I am **cloning**.

Sometimes this works, but sometimes I end up with a button that still expands and contracts the original div, even though when I inspect the HTML, the IDs look correct.

I suspect that the event handler that is copied may be hard coding the reference to the id of the div to be expanded and contracted, which is why just fixing the IDs in the DOM elements doesn't work. However, that doesn't explain why some of the clones work and others do not.

What is the correct way to clone something that has bootstrap behaviors attached to it?

So, a couple of answers have pointed out that just removing `true` from my `clone()` call will avoid copying the event listener.  So I now realize that my problem is a little more complicated than the one I oversimplified here.  I will ask it as a separate question. ([Cloning a Bootstrap element but not all of the event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707524/cloning-a-bootstrap-element-but-not-all-of-the-event-listeners))

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @jonju I added the javascript I am using to modify the clone.

Comment: what is objectContainer in above code ?

Comment: what is the `collapsibleObjCounter` ? if you are doing this in some loop please provide the comple code block of cloning logic. It will be helpful. Thank you

Comment: I tried to create a jsfiddle but I couldn't get the bootstrap stuff to work properly.  objectContainer is a div that contains the button and the other div.  collapsibleObjCounter is just a counter, a global variable that is used to create new IDs for each new collapse target

Comment: Please see the JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2fgoywzy/1/) I have provided. And let me know if that is what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Moreover, description is given in detail in my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So far your code is ok, just remove `true` from `clone()` it's not needed.

**UPDATED**

> This **Boolean** value indicates whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. The default value is to the **false** . So, when we were calling the `.clone()` method without passing any **Boolean** value, it was just copying the elements but not the **event handlers** attached to it. But, when we pass the value **true** , it copies both the elements and any **event handlers** attached to it.

But **Bootstrap** is handling the **event handlers** for dynamic objects so you don't need to `true` in clone.

**LIKE**

If you're handling `events` for dynamic objects using this way

```
$(".btn").click(.....); 
// This button was dynamically created and you want a click event for it, 
// but it wont work because at the time of event binding this button wasn't exist at all.
```

**BUT**

You need to handle **events** for dynamic objects using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) technique.

```
 $(document).on("click",".btn",function(){ .... });
```

This will work, because the event handler is bound to an element higher up the `DOM` tree (in this case, the document) and will be executed when an event reaches that element having originated on an element matching the selector,
And that's what **Bootstrap** does for dynamic objects, also you do the same if needed for dynamic objects. Hers is **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/dt8v51m1/)** for this.

Also you need to wrap the whole `collapsible` part in a `div` for cloning.

> **Note:** Using `.clone()` has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate `id` attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead.

So, you need to update `data-target` and `div` **id** attribute after cloning, so that newly created button `targets` the newly created collapse panel

I am using **jQuery** for it.

Here is the code **Snippet**

```js
$(function(){
  var target = "collapsible_obj_";
  var i = 1;
  
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $(".parent_colapse:last").clone().insertAfter(".parent_colapse:last");        
    $(".parent_colapse:last > button").attr("data-target", "#"+target+i);
    $(".parent_colapse:last .collapse").attr("id", target+i);
    i++;
  });
  
  $(document).on("click",".button",function(){
     alert();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent_colapse">
<button aria-expanded="false" data-target="#collapsible_obj_0" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-link collapsed">click here</button>

<div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapsible_obj_0" class="collapse">
  <span>foo</span>
  <button type="button" class="button">click</button>
</div>
  </div>
<button type="button" id="button">Clone</button>
```

**About** your question you haven't shown your full `script` that's the reason we are unable to find the bug. **LIKE** we don't know `objectContainer` nor `collapsibleObjCounter` what that is ?

Comment: Can you explain how your code works?  Is it the case that you are ignoring the bootstrap built-in collapse behavior and implementing it directly?

Comment: No i am not ignoring the built-in behavior of bootstrap, The bootstrap collapse events occurs only when there is `click` on `data-target` Node having `toggle` attribute functionality, so i am not ignoring the behavior i am modifying the clone part with new `target`.

Comment: How is what you're doing to modify the clone different than what I'm doing with `header.find(".collapse").attr("id", collapseId);` and 
  `header.find("button[data-toggle='collapse']").attr("data-target", "#"+collapseId);`   I have confirmed by inspecting my generated HTML that this is working.

Comment: @PurpleVermont so far your code is ok just remove `true` from `clone()`, About your question you haven't shown your full `script` that's the reason we are unable to find the `bug`. **LIKE** we don't know `objectContainer` nor `collapsibleObjCounter` what that is ? That's the reason i created separate and easy solution for you. Hope you understand.

Comment: I think you're right that just removing `true` from `clone()` would fix the problem I am seeing.  What if there are other event handlers within the container div that I do need to clone as-is?

Comment: Just forgot to mention in my answer :)

Comment: The real key point to this answer is removing the true flag from the clone() statement.  It would improve the answer if you explain why this is necessary.

Comment: @PurpleVermont i improve my answer with much explanation and the best of knowledge, you can check the answer again. Hope that helps. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't copy the events while cloning, remove the `true` flag.

```
var header = objectContainer.clone();
```

My guess is Bootstrap is handling the event binding of dynamic objects also for data-toggle, it only needs to have different id's & target.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tt6dnkz9/).

PS: Don't know what was this or objectContainer in OP's question, so created a closure and pasting result in new wrapper.

Comment: So, this works except... I was posting oversimplified code and there are other buttons within the container div whose event handlers I do need to copy.  Is there some way I could clone with the `true` flag and then remove the relevant listener, in a way that would cause bootstrap to re-add the needed listener?

Comment: You may try delegating those events handlers at some-point above in the DOM tree with the use  of `.on()`, so that you may not need to copy those at all and it will work just fine for the dynamic nodes as well (via bubbling). eg.
`$('body').on('click', '.someBtn', someFunc)`

This will trigger the event handler **someFunc** on click of **someBtn** even if it is added dynamically later on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not caused by the event listeners *in and of themselves*. The issue is how Bootstrap works. For most of the Bootstrap components, Bootstrap creates a JavaScript object associated with the DOM element. **This object is what you need to take care of when you clone Bootstrap components.** For a `collapse` element, Bootstrap creates a [`Collapse` object](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/e8c5de398013ab5334180a7f26251a98a5165997/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L554).

The JavaScript object is associated with the DOM element through jQuery's `$.data`. *This* is the problem. If you use jQuery's `clone` and request that event handlers be copied to the clone, then you also get a copy of the data set with `$.data`. However, when the data is a reference to a JavaScript object, then it is the *reference* that is copied to the clone. So the original and the clone refer to the same JavaScript object and this is where everything goes astray. This is not special to Bootstrap, by the way: any reference is subject to this problem.

What you could do is perform a `$.removeData` on the cloned elements that are Bootstrap components. This will force Bootstrap to recreate the JavaScript object. For components that automatically enroll in the data API, this should be all that's needed. (`collapse` automatically enrolls.) For components that do *not* automatically enroll (e.g. tooltips), you need to call `$.[component]` to recreate the component manually.

I've [forked a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hm3c065q/) from [aManHasNoName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38692890/1906307)'s fiddle that illustrates this. The only modifications were:

1. Add the parameters `true, true` to  `var header = objectContainer.clone();`
2. Modify `header.find(".collapse").attr("id", collapseId)` to add `.removeData()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a JSFiddle of your code. The most possible error seems to that you where using a `this.collapsibleObjCounter++` value of `0` that might be creating an issue.

Here is a working JSFiddle. Please let me know if that is what you are trying to do. Thank you.

> https://jsfiddle.net/2fgoywzy/1/

---

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) { 
    var objectContainer =  $("#main");
    var header = objectContainer.clone(true);
    var counter = i; // replace this with this.collapsibleObjCounter++
    var collapseId = "collapsible_obj_" + counter;

    header.find(".collapse").attr("id", collapseId);
    header.find("button[data-toggle='collapse']").attr("data-target", "#"+collapseId);
    $(header).appendTo('body');
}
});
```

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <button aria-expanded="false" data-target="#collapsible_obj_0" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-link collapsed">click here</button>

    <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapsible_obj_0" class="collapse">
        <span>foo</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you are having a value of `0` in `this.collapsibleObjCounter++` then i would suggest doing `++this.collapsibleObjCounter`. Instead of **post increment** do **pre increment**

Comment: Why would having a zero value be a problem?  It's just part of a string.  (I'm definitely not repeating IDs if that is your concern.)

Comment: yes repeating IDs was my concern. So what I have shown in pluncker is not what you want ?