# Cloning a Bootstrap element but not all of the event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, clone

In this question [Cloning a bootstrap element with an event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670597/cloning-a-bootstrap-element-with-an-event-listener) I asked how to clone an element without copying the bootstrap-supplied event listener.  And the answer is to not pass `true` to the `clone()` command.

As it turns out, I see now that my problem is a bit more complicated than that.  What I actually have is a div containing several buttons, one of which controls the expand/collapse of an associated div, and others of which provide other specialized functionality, which are provided by complex click listeners added within the javascript when creating the original.  I need to keep the click() listeners on those other buttons.  If I call `clone()` without the `true` argument, I lose all those listeners as well.

So is there some way I can `clone(true)` with listeners, but remove the bootstrap-provided cloned listener from the expand/contract button, change the IDs to be unique IDs, and then somehow still get bootstrap provide that collapse functionality (add the listener again, I guess, based on the new changed IDs in the cloned div)?

I am creating a bunch of different collapsible objects, and then cloning some of them (into another tab pane).

A simplified version of my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <button aria-expanded="false" data-target="#collapsible_obj_0"    data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-link collapsed">click here</button>
  <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapsible_obj_0" class="collapse">
    <span>foo</span>
    <button class="btn bar-btn">bar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a snippet from the javascript:

```
  $("#collapsible-obj-0 .bar-btn").click(function () {
    // do a bunch of stuff
  });

  this.collapsibleObjCounter = 15;  // really this will be one more than the number of exiting objects

  // objectContainer is the jquery object representing the top level div (passed into this method)

  var header = objectContainer.clone(true); // or not true, that is the question....
  var counter = this.collapsibleObjCounter++;
  var collapseId = "collapsible_obj_" + counter;
  header.find(".collapse").attr("id", collapseId);
  header.find("button[data-toggle='collapse']").attr("data-target", "#"+collapseId);
```

What I need here is to remove the event handler on the "click here" button and have bootstrap add a fresh one based on the changed IDs.  If I clone without the `true` flag that seems to work correctly but I lose the click() functionality of the "bar" button.  In reality I have a lot of "bar" buttons whose functionality I need to keep.  So manually copying the click() behaviors to the cloned versions would be messy, but possible.  But ideally I think what I want is a way to just remove the one event handler when I change the IDs on the collapse button and associated div, and get bootstrap to put a new one on automagically.

I apologize that this isn't runnable code - there's so much context that it's hard to pull out a streamlined runnable example.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to delegate those events handlers with the use of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$('body').on('click', '.bar-btn', someFunc);
```

Added a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tt6dnkz9/2/) with added delegated handler.

> Benefits of event delegation:
>
> - You may not need to copy/clone those handlers at all
> - It will work just fine for the nodes added dynamically in the DOM at a later time as well (via bubbling).

So, the above code will trigger the event handler **someFunc** on click of **bar-btn** even if it is after cloning and pasting an instance of  objectContainer.

To learn more, check out these links about [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) and [bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing).