# Cloning content that has been dynamically changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div that is dynamically changed according to what user clicks. For example if he clicks button, image will appear in div.

But when i try to clone() this element, it only clones with its original content. No image there. How can i solve this?

```js
$(".clickme").click(function(){
  $(".testDiv").html("testcontent");
  $(".testDiv").clone().prependTo(".testDiv");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testDiv"></div>
<button class="clickme">click</button>
```

[Photo example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYO0I.png)

Comment: You can find detailed answer for cloning here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670597/cloning-a-bootstrap-element-with-an-event-listener/38692667#38692667

Comment: Your code works fine. There's a clone of  `.testDiv` nested before the content of the original `.testDiv`. You'll have to replicate your code with the exact layout of HTML.

Comment: M.Tanzil solution worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with :

```
$(document).on("click",".clickme",function()
{
  $(".testDiv").html("testcontent");
  $(".testDiv").clone().prependTo(".testDiv");
});
```

It will allow you to use the css/html dynamic changes.